# SP13 - Disallow edit permission to users but give enough to interact with wfl

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In Sharepoint 2013, I have problems with my permissions on my site that runs a nintex workflow only when a new item is created/added. Information integrity is important to us and we dont want our users to edit the item they created, if they made a mistake they must make a new item for a new workflow to start.

Our problem is that some users need permissions high enough to answer tasks for our workflow (we have them at 'Contribute' level) but those permissions are also high enough to allow them to edit their item with the quick edit.

Disabling quick edit is a choice but the only way is disabling for everyone and that is a no.

What can we do to have our permissions levels more specialized? In general, only a few trusted people can edit items (there are some parts that need manual edit). What we want is:

- A group that allows new items creation (therefore a new workflow run) but no item edit/delete permissions
- A group that can answer workflow tasks but no item edit/delete permissions
- A group that is just for viewing, with no item edit/delete/add permissions
- A group with high enough permissions to allow all the above mentioned.

What are the permissions we must assign? Do new groups must be created? What rules must we apply to those groups to work as intended?

Any solution that requires coding in an IDE is out of the table since due company policies I cant have an IDE.

If you need more information, please ask.

Comment: You need to read up on permissions, for instance there is a difference between 'Contribute' permissions and 'Edit' permissions.  Are you confusing the two?  [MS link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)

Comment: Contribute permissions automatically give edit permissions. And contribute permission is necessary to start workflows and/or answer its tasks. What I want is a custom permission level that wont give edit or delete permissions but that will give users enough to interact with our workflows.

Comment: Would creating new permission level be a solution? You could set only the `Add Items` permission for the role #1. [How to create a new SharePoint 2013 permission level](https://billing.plexhosted.com/knowledgebase/278/How-to-create-a-new-SharePoint-2013-permissions-level-.html)

Comment: Yes, but it still allows another users to edit it because they still need contibute permissions to answer workflow tasks